# how do you add users input from multiple entries, and add them together

Tags: python, tkinter

Example

```
ballEntry = Entry(window,width=10, textvariable=total)
TenisballlEntry = Entry(window,width=10, textvariable=total)


total =  ballEntry.get() + TenisballlEntry.get()
```

I don't know how to take the input from the what the users enter, and then sort of "turn them" into an integer that the program can understand so they can be added?

Comment: This is too broad/vague. You'll probably be better served by a tutorial, guide, or some documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want numerical input from the user then just try converting those to integers or floats before adding them.

Like this:

```
e1 = int(ballEntry.get())
e2 = int(TenisballlEntry.get())

total = e1 + e2
```

Or:

```
e1 = float(ballEntry.get())
e2 = float(TenisballlEntry.get())

total = e1 + e2
```

Comment: It adds them together, so like lets say the ballEntry was 10 and the TenisballEntry was 10, it would be 1010 not 20. How would I get it to be 20?

Comment: Sorry brother my mistake I have corrected it now